# iOS Web Testing w/ Appium

Tags: java, ios, selenium, appium, selenium-grid

- I am using real devices
- I am attempting web-based testing
- I have a fully working TestNG suite for Android

I can't figure out how to perform the same testing on iOS.

The error I get is:

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: A new session could not be created. (Original error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c ideviceinstaller -u A7BD67F34FA1B94651C832041B4DEE720DC2CBC1 -i /var/folders/0x/z8gpmw7923d8gw9k14rdj0gh3qx1yt/T/115105-3319-10zvjv1/SafariLauncher.app
No iOS device found, is it plugged in?)
```

Im starting my selenium grid node with `appium --nodeconfig /path/to/config.json -p 4623 --safari` and with the JSON configs:

```
{
"capabilities":
[
{
"browserName":"Safari",
"deviceName": "iPod 5",
"udid":"A7BD67F34FA1B94651C832041B4DEE720DC2CBC1",
"version":"8.4.1",
"maxInstances": 5,
"platform":"MAC",
"platformName": "iOS"
}
],
"configuration":
{
"cleanUpCycle":2000,
"timeout":10000,
"proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy", 
"url":"http://0.0.0.0:4623/wd/hub",
"maxSession": 5,
"port": 4623,
"host": "0.0.0.0",
"register": true,
"registerCycle": 5000,
"hubPort": 4444,
"hubHost": "localhost"
}
```

and my java to create the IOSDriver is:

```
public static IOSDriver getIOSDriver(String udid) throws MalformedURLException{

        String SELENIUM_HUB_URL = "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub";
        ThreadLocal<IOSDriver> driver = null;  

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();   
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "iPod 5");
        capabilities.setCapability("udid", udid);
        capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.MAC);
        capabilities.setCapability("verison", "8.4.1");
        capabilities.setCapability("platfromName", "iOS");
        capabilities.setCapability("browserName", "Safari");

        try {
            driver = new ThreadLocal<IOSDriver>();
            driver.set(new IOSDriver(new URL(SELENIUM_HUB_URL),
                    capabilities));
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            System.out.println("Tackle Issue with RemoteDriverSetup");
        }
        driver.get().manage().timeouts()
                .pageLoadTimeout(20L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get().manage().timeouts()
                .implicitlyWait(20L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        return driver.get();
    }
```

To clarify, the device **is** plugged in and safariLauncher has been deployed from xCode, which is able to find the device.

Am I missing something fundamental here?

Thanks for your help,

Liam

Comment: are you sure device and deviceName should be assigned value udid? http://appium.io/slate/en/master/?python#server-flags

Comment: Honestly its probably not the intended use, but from experimenting with this on Android it seems to be just String comparison. Will update tomorrow when I try using the correct information, thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found the solution to this problem. The UDID of the device given by iTunes for the device was `A7BD67F34FA1B94651C832041B4DEE720DC2CBC1`:

[image: iTunes UDID]

But the xCode UDID was `a7bd67f34fa1b94651c832041b4dee720dc2cbc1` (the same but all lower case):

[image]

The issue was solved by using xCode's version of the UDID. This is found in xCode using `ctrl+shift+2`.

So the capabilities look like this:

```
{
"capabilities":
[
{
"browserName":"Safari",
"deviceName": "iPod 5",
"udid":"a7bd67f34fa1b94651c832041b4dee720dc2cbc1",
"version":"8.4.1",
"maxInstances": 5,
"platform":"MAC",
"platformName": "iOS"
}
],
"configuration":
{
"cleanUpCycle":2000,
"timeout":10000,
"proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy", 
"url":"http://0.0.0.0:4623/wd/hub",
"maxSession": 5,
"port": 4623,
"host": "0.0.0.0",
"register": true,
"registerCycle": 5000,
"hubPort": 4444,
"hubHost": "localhost"
}
}
```

and the testNG.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="Suite" parallel="tests" thread-count="2">
  <test name="Nexus 7">
    <parameter name="udid"  value="08da76c1" />
    <classes>
      <class name="testNG.TestOne"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
  <test name="HTC desrire">
    <parameter name="udid"  value="SH48CWT00563" />
    <classes>
      <class name="testNG.TestOne"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
    <test name="iPod Touch">
    <parameter name="udid"  value="a7bd67f34fa1b94651c832041b4dee720dc2cbc1" />
    <classes>
      <class name="testNG.TestTwo"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

I thought this was very strange, but it seems to work.

Liam.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to provide bundle id-
capabilities.setCapability("bundleID", "com.safariLauncher.safariLauncher");

Safari launcher is automatically launched in the device and then it redirects to the native safari app in the real device. Also, you don't need to build safari launcher from xcode. Safari launcher is packaged with the appium setup itself (you need apple dev certificate and provide it as argument to reset.sh script).Appium documentation explains all the steps to do it. I suggest you to go through the appium documentation.